# Jupiter temperature units preference?

Tags: jupiter

I'm using Jupiter to manage my CPU speed.  Is there a place to change it to display the core temp in Fahrenheit?  I can't find the config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The temperature in Celsius is hard-wired into Jupiter.

Fortunately, Jupiter is written in Python - this makes it very easy to change.

First backup your copy of jupiter:

```
cp /usr/bin/jupiter ~/jupiter
```

Next edit the file:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/bin/jupiter
```

Find the following section in the file:

```
def get_temperature(self):
        temp = int(self.collect_data(self.temp))
        temp = temp / 1000
        return str(temp) + ' ºC'
```

change to:

```
def get_temperature(self):
    temp = int(self.collect_data(self.temp))
    temp = temp / 1000
    temp = ((temp * 9) / 5) + 32
    return str(temp) + ' ºF'
```

Save, logout and login.

[image]

Obviously, an update to the jupiter PPA will overwrite your changes.

You can either disable the PPA, or save `/usr/bin/jupiter` as (for example) `/usr/bin/jupiter2`.  In your startup applications, change the jupiter startup command to `python /usr/bin/jupiter2`